# Can a sealed or static class be declared inside a sealed class in C#?

Tags: c#, sealed

These are two separate questions:

1. Can a class marked as *sealed* be present inside a sealed class?
2. Can a class marked as *static* be present inside a sealed class?

These questions are just out to have better understanding of the core concepts. Can anyone highlight the practical usage of above concept?

Comment: The question title and body are contradictory. Is the inner class sealed or static?

Comment: This can very easily be tested.

Comment: i have two questions ,title has first question and the second question is in the summary.

Comment: If you have two questions, make it explicit, please. Either post two separate questions, or just say so in the question body. As it is, your question is plain confusing. You can edit your OP to fix that. Thank you.

Comment: @itsme86 : i don't have machine right now to test the given question.this questions jst came into my mind and so i posted.

Comment: Much better now; thanks.

Answer (score 3):

C# supports the concept of a *nested* class.  Using term "super class" is not appropriate, that implies that the nested class has an inheritance relationship.  There is none whatsoever, the term "outer class" is appropriate.

It is useful only to control accessibility.  A nested class has access to the private members of the outer class.  And most useful, you can declare a nested class *private* so it is completely invisible to any code outside of the outer class.  A much stronger guarantee than the default *internal* provides.

So what follows is that declaring the outer class sealed has no consequence to the nested class.  Easy to see for yourself by just experimenting with it.

Comment: what about inheritance relationship inside sealed class,a nested class declared as public internal sealed inside the class ,the public member function of a class can be used in the other classes inside the same assembly.

Comment: i want to have a broader view on the concept of sealed.

Comment: Well, it should be obvious from the answer that declaring a nested class *public* is not very useful.  That's just equivalent to using a different namespace name.  Again, there's no inheritance relationship between the nested and the outer class, C# is not Java.  So *sealed* is irrelevant since that controls inheritance.

Comment: what i wanted to understand : take a normal scenario -  a class having 3 to 4 nested class and there exist an inheritance relationship between two class . - i hope you will  agree on this.

Comment: Now the actual scenario :-  a sealed class having 3 to 4 nested class and there exist a inheritance relationship between them and now i want to use the member function of nested class present in the sealed class outside the namespace . i can do so , but the question here is how to instantiate a class that has private constructor and without using reflection

Comment: The notion that this is a "normal scenario" is just off the table.  It is not.  What happens if you try anyway is entirely normal, your nested class cannot derive from a sealed class.  Of course it can't, it is sealed.  Don't you have a compiler to just try this yourself?  The Express edition is readily available for free.

Comment: Sorry, i am talking about the inheritance relationship between the classes inside the sealed class. i am not talking about inheriting the sealed class. Hope i am able to make you understand :)

Comment: i am right now in my home and not have access to system to check the scenarios mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can place a `static class` inside a `sealed class`.

The following is perfectly valid:

```
public sealed class SealedClass
{
    public static class StaticClass 
    { 

    }
}
```

The Vice-versa is also valid:

```
public static class SealedClass
{
    public sealed class StaticClass 
    { 

    }
}
```

### What is `sealed` class?

They cannot be inherited. It improves the performance when compiling and runtime.

### What is `static` class?

They cannot be instantiated.

Comment: its worth while stating that the sealed keyword improves performance slightly at both compile time and runtime.